# Could this be the source of the sewage smell?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

Recently a plumber came and fitted a new pan connector to my toilet. It needed to be replaced and there was a sewage smell for about a week before it was replaced.

Since then the smell has reduced but hasn’t gone. And in fact is getting worse day by day.

Investigating it I found that the pan connector seems very loose on the back of the toilet. I can move and wiggle it with one finger.

[image]

I will post a video of it...
https://youtu.be/X-4e2jS0ZW0

Could this be the source of the sewage smell? I presume it should be an airtight connection? So any amount of looseness will cause air to escape?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where does that corrugated hose go?

Comment: @DanielGriscom, that is the connection to the sewer line .... the toilet does not connect to the sewer through the floor

Comment: maybe the original sewage smell was not caused by a defective pan connector

Comment: Its not at all clear to me that that connection is the problem. From  the little I know, there is a flexible rubber connector between the toilet and the sewer line, so movement like you are seeing would not seem to indicate thats where the smell is coming from (but I guess it is possible).

Comment: @jsotola hi, no it connects via a 4” pipe to an external pipe that takes it down to the floor. I’m on the 2nd floor (3rd if you’re American). I only found out about toilets that connect through the floor when looking for this. That must be an American thing i think.

Comment: @davidgo ok. Thank you. That makes sense. I’ve called the plumber out to take a look. Hopefully they’ll find something.